# What is the compatible eclipse CDT version for GDB 7.5

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am using GDB 7.5 cross compiled for PowerPC platforms. I want to know what version of eclipse CDT should I use for remote debugging using that GDB.

I searched the eclipse documentation, I could not find any note on compatible GDB versions for eclipse releases.

I have tried using eclipse Neon, Oxygen and Luna. In each version, some or the other feature does not seem to work. For example, Neon is not able to recognize the file path when I am trying to put breakpoints, whereas in Luna, it is able to do it perfectly.

Also, I use GCC 4.6.2 over cygwin (windows 7) to compile the code. Can windows be the root of my problem, as I have read for some eclipse features that they are tested primarily on linux.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in my target stub implementation of GDB RSP protocol.

Once the target side stub is written properly, eclipse Oxygen works best among the versions I have mentioned in question.